# GET parameter won't pass with html button formaction

Tags: php, html, forms, get

I am trying to pass a GET parameter through a button but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. The parameter is set, as it shows up fine in the header, but it isn't being added to the edit.php url. The button is directing me to edit.php, just without the GET parameter added. I am pretty new to this stuff and this is my first time using links that aren't through anchor tags, so I am clearly missing something here. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

```
<h1 class="headerWithButton">Claim #<?echo($_GET['claim_id'])?>
    <form>
        <button type="submit" formaction="index.php" class="backButton">Back</button>
        <?echo('<button type="submit" formaction="edit.php?claim_id='.$_GET['claim_id'].'" class="editButton">Edit</button>');?>
    </form>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit a form using the `GET` method, any existing query string in the `action` will be replaced by a new one generated by the `name` and `value` of the successful controls associated with that form.

In your case, the only successful control is the submit button, which doesn't have a `name` or a `value`.

You could get the effect you desire by moving the data to those attributes:

```
<h1 class="headerWithButton">Claim #<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['claim_id']); ?>
    <form>
        <button formaction="index.php" class="backButton">Back</button>
        <button formaction="edit.php" name="claim_id" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['claim_id']); ?>" class="editButton">Edit</button>
    </form>
</h1>
```

**Important** security note: inserting data from the URL directly into a page makes you highly vulnerable to [XSS attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). You need to take precautions against that. The most basic of those is using `htmlspecialchars`.

---

Note, however, that it isn't really appropriate to use a form here. Your form buttons are not submitting any data the user has entered, nor performing any kind of action. The [affordances](https://uxplanet.org/ux-design-glossary-how-to-use-affordances-in-user-interfaces-393c8e9686e4) offered by buttons are misleading here.

You can, and should, use regular links instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="get" action="edit.php">
        <?echo('<button type="submit" formaction="edit.php?claim_id='.$_GET['claim_id'].'" class="editButton">Edit</button>');?>
    </form>
```

instead of using the form you can just use a straightforward link
k with the anchor tag

```
<a href="edit.php?claim_id="<?=$_GET['claim_id']?>">edit</a>
```

or you can specify the methos of get on the form with a hidden for input to place the link get parameter

Answer (score 0):

here it is better to place buttons in different blocks. But personally, in this case, I use a hyperlink

1. `<form method="get" action=""></form>`
2. `<?echo('<a href="edit.php?claim_id='.$_GET['claim_id'].'" class="editButton">Edit</a>`

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use formaction, you must specify name and value of element:

```
<h1 class="headerWithButton">Claim #<? echo($_GET['claim_id'])?>
<form>
    <button type="submit" formaction="index.php" class="backButton">Back</button>
    <?php echo('<button type="submit" formaction="/edit.php" name="claim_id" value="'.$_GET['claim_id'].'" class="editButton">Edit</button>');?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the easiest way to pass values with a button is to just wrap a form around the button.

```
$id = $_GET['claim_id'];

echo <<<EOT
<form action="index.php" method="get">
<button>Back</button>
</form>
<form action="edit.php" method="get">
<button name="claim_id" value="$id">Edit</button>
</form>
EOT;
```